# Redirecting from one value to another using action link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When I click on the column values in a table, it should redirect me to another table which has a common id, but a different view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Vendor)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.VendorName, "@item.Site Name", new { Id = item.VendorName})
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.SiteCount
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.LastReviewType
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.LastReviewDate
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.TeamLead
        </td>
        ...
```

When I click on the **vendorname** values in the table, it should take me to the table which shows the sites which are assigned to the vendor.

Comment: so you want to redirect to another view ? and what is this for `"@item.Site Name"`?

Comment: Not clear do you want to redirect to the section on the same page or to a different page? Please define `it should take me to the table`

Comment: "@item.Site Name" it is a dummy ,,dont mind abt that...i have vendor list in one table where vendor id is a hyperlink,,it has vendor id which is hidden,when i click on the vendor name it should direct me to the table where the respective sites are assigned to the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would have a controller by the name **VendorController** which has an action **SiteList** which would take argument **venderId** to generate the view, you could use

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.VendorName, “SiteList” /*Name of the action*/, “Vendor” /* Name of the controller */, new { venderId = item.VendorId } /* parameter */)
```

If the action is on the same controller which generated the first table, you may ignore `/* Name of the controller argument */`, thus

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.VendorName, “SiteList” /*Name of the action*/, new { venderId = item.VendorId } /* parameter */)
```

Hope this will help you